Unexpected behavior of the mov instruction in GAS when using Intel syntax
Consider this code:
            .intel_syntax noprefix

            .data
l:          .long 0

            .text
            .global main
main:   
        mov DWORD PTR l, 0x11111111
        mov eax, DWORD PTR 0
        mov al, l

The last instruction doesn't load in al the address of l. Instead, it loads the value at this address. In this case, it loads 0x11. Why? I couldn't find any answers in the GNU assembler manual... How do I load in a register the address of l?

mov al, l and mov al, [l] both do the same thing..

mov al, offset l ?

It loads the address of l with offset. Thanks. But I can't find anything about offset in GAS manual..

@MartinChekurov Intel syntax as supported by the GNU assembler is meant to be compatible with MASM.  Refer to the MASM manual for details on it.

Aside: al isn't wide enough to hold an address.

Aside 2: l is a poor choice for the name of a label. It's easily confounded with 1. Which is exactly what I did when I first read mov al, l.

@SepRoland: AL is an 8-bit register.  0x11 is hex, not binary (0b00010001).  Two hex digits is 8 bit width, what you get from truncating 0x11111111 to 8-bit.

@PeterCordes My bad. I mistakenly took it for a binary. Deleting the comment. Thanks for noticing.

@MartinChekurov: See  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info re: different flavours in Intel syntax, as well as the linked duplicates.
